# How to find out if this sword is real or just a souvenir?

Tags: identification, sword

I received an old looking sword as a gift. The giving party has no information on the piece whatsoever, as it was bought online, on our local version of craigslist.

[image]

The blade is very blunt. So blunt in fact, that it could just be a sword bought by a Tourist. If so, I would like to sharpen it and use as decor. Also, the handle is fitted with a piece of felt in between. --> Probably used to reduce play, instead of fitting the pieces together more precisely.

[image]

However this sword is made with more effort than I would expect for a Touri-piece. (Mostly because of an intricate Handle, and an etch on the blade)

[image]

As this sword has no year, maker or similar engraved / etched, on it, I'm not sure where to start looking for some background of the piece. (with the exception of Toledo, (?)where this sword maybe came from(?))

How could I proceed to make sure it realy is just a souvenir? Would some pictures be helpful?

Does anyone know:

1. blunt swords not used as decor?
2. real swords with no makers-mark?

EDIT 1:
added pictures and Dimensions:

- length of blade 80cm / 31 inches
- length of handle 20cm / 8 inches (with hand-guard)
- width of blade (base) 33mm / 1.3 inches
- width of blade (behind the tip) 20mm / 0.8 inches

@MAGolding see this image for a close-up of the coat of arms. seems like to boars and to Stars on opposite sides. 
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include photos (preferably with both sides and with dimensions)? Without these, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks, edited my original post. If there are some details of interest I haven't photographed, let me know!

Comment: This is not a saber, it is some other kind of sword.

Comment: oh, alright, sorry for using the wrong terminology. (edited it)

Comment: Photographs of the whole blade would help. If that engraving on the blade extends close to the tip, you can be pretty sure it's an expensive tourist piece. Cleaning an engraved blade after use would be very difficult and inadequate cleaning would let rusting start rapidly.

Comment: engraving is about on a third of the blade.

Comment: @Marco If you want to research a little about the model, you have a cup-hilted rapier, early 16th century-style. It might be a reproduction of the Tizona made in the Toledo factory in Spain, because they make some of them now as "Roperas de cazuela" (cup-hilted rapiers).

Comment: I would say focus more on replicas of the [Carlos III rapiers](https://www.google.com/search?q=toledo+carlos+3++rapier&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj_opHKhcXnAhVBIX0KHTriBvkQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=toledo+carlos+3++rapier&gs_l=img.12...435603.439692..457715...0.0..0.97.809.9......0....1..gws-wiz-img.L69juMs5KMo&ei=6UdAXr-KBcHC9AO6xJvIDw&bih=886&biw=1745&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS865US865&hl=en#imgrc=xvwRzkDn8jhk7M)

Comment: I note that the hilt has what looks like a coat of arms.  Adding a good picture of the coat of arms might be helpful.  All I can say at the moment is that it looks like an bend between to other charges..

Comment: The style of lettering of the "Toledo" near the hilt, and the vine design make me think 1870 or later. As part of the taste described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Nouveau .

Comment: @MAGolding been trying to work out the blazon, (difficult without tinctures) *on a bend, between mullets, two ???? heads*. can't tell what heads these are, and if there is a special term when they face each other.

Comment: the heads seem to be boars. (added better picture) On the Backside the coat of arms is different, showing only a lion within the "shield-contour". The lion is upright, looking to the left, and has an odly long tail.

Comment: Is there some writing on the undecorated slightly thinner part of the blade between the guard and the bell? (Visible, maybe, on your  2nd photo?)

Comment: unfortunately no, there are some scratches, and a darker part in pretty much the center of the blade. -kinda splotchy, extending through the bell to the knight. (maybe visible on the last picture) not sure why. maybe some kind of forge-scale? (...or just some liquid was on there for too long. )

Comment: FWIW to me the tip of the guard in the first image looks like it was (poorly) injection molded or something to the same effect. To my mind that makes it look like it was made for tourists.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy which part? the brown frontmost part of the guard is felt. (btw. no writing under the felt, I checked) Do you mean the part on the inside of the bell, with its draft angle?

Comment: @Marco: This [dick-like bit](https://imgur.com/a/31KudiP). A lateral view of that area to surface how it was made might further help to confirm the hunch. But judging by the pic in question, molten steel was poured in between two molds. That would make it firmly recent -- and low quality at that.

Comment: accordingly to stephan slater book, the blazon is 'a bend engoulé' He says it is a common device on spanish heraldry. In the book there is a similar shield, but without the stars

Comment: That blade pattern looks very much like one on a stamped-metal sword a friend brought back for me from Spain around 1982-83. I'll see I can dig it out of the back of my closet...

Comment: .... and? I didn't even consider stamping, and although quite deep, I think it would be feasible.

Comment: @Marco It's a different pattern, more abstract floral, with "Toledo" and "Spain" near the hilt where yours says "Toledo." My stamped pattern is also angled slightly off-center and doesn't look as distinct as yours.

Comment: @Marco I have added an answer that is too long for a comment.  It has some information about the coat of arms.

Answer (score 2):

More images would be useful to be sure, but to me this part of the guard awfully looks like the sword was made using die casting (and it was poorly done so, at that):

[image: Not a dick pic]

Best I can recollect this type of stuff wasn't even possible until the late 19th century when foundries could achieve heat strong enough that you could actually melt steel.

(Another tell in my mind is the precision of the blade decoration. Even if we leave aside the rust issue raised in the question's comments (i.e. it wouldn't be functional as a blade) on the basis that it could be ceremonial blade, it still leaves the issue of it being way too precise for forged steel to my taste. But don't take my word for it here, it's just a hunch.)

Comment: gotcha, now I know which part ;D         - Is a sword usually rust-resistant?

Comment: the blade-decorations could be etched, I can't see any traces of engraving / grinding on the lower surface

Comment: Can't really tell on the photo, but this part of the guard doesn't really look like steel (and probably isn't the same material as the handle or the blade). Could be aluminum, which would mean it was made in 1890s or later. Also, the correct term to use for metalworking process would be "die casting", "injection molding" is only used with plastic.

Comment: @Marco: Usually you don't want your sword to rust, so you keep it clean. Engravings like those in your pictures simply guarantee that you'll need more than a 30s wipe of the blade to get rid of any blood on it.

Comment: Alright, I guess they didn't know what chrome can do in steel back in the days ;D

Comment: Also, I checked, the only magnetic part of sword is the blade and "bell". Handle is non magnetic. (all 3 parts of it)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy speaking of the blade... such a sword / rapier would usually have  a sharp blade, right? (because of my intention to sharpen it.)

Comment: @Marco: Insofar as I've understood metallurgy, not every metal will behave well when you hit something. So much so, in fact, that shattered blades weren't unheard of in medieval battles -- better your battle tested grandfather's blade than a shiny new blade that might die on you the first time it is struck by a superior sword. Anyway, if the blade is meant to be strictly decorative you might be better off leaving it as is. (Plus, you never know when a kid might play with a sword.)

Comment: @Marco: My son inherited his great grandfather's Dutch Militia Officer's sword, and had it refurbished for his commissioning in the Canadian Armed Forces. At that time we were instructed that a sword blade should be wiped down 3 or 4 times a year with a light oil (sewing machine oil was suggested) and stored ***outside*** the scabbard. The danger is that temperature cycles can result in condensation inside the scabbard, that if allowed to sit in contact with the blade will cause corrosion.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens thanks a lot for the guidance on the sword-care!

Comment: if you look closely at  the grip you can also see what was a air bubble in one of the arms of the cherub. So more evidence for casting.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment so I made it an answer.

The arms on the sword are rather familiar looking.

Here is a link to an image of the coat of arms of Spanish dictator Francisco Franco.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbols_of_Francoism#/media/File:Coat_of_Arms_of_Francisco_Franco_as_Head_of_the_Spanish_State.svg[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbols_of_Francoism#/media/File:Coat_of_Arms_of_Francisco_Franco_as_Head_of_the_Spanish_State.svg)

It has a similar design to the one on the sword, a bend going between two heads and mouths, and two other charges.

In this case the heads are identified as dragons, and the charges are the Pillars of Hercules.

The bend between two dragon's mouths is described as The Royal Band of Castile.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Band_of_Castile[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Band_of_Castile)

So it appears that the coat of arms, genuine or fictional, on the sword was inspired by the Royal Band of Castile.

I hope this may help you learn the nature of the sword.